# get tags based on the next following-sibling only. xpath

Tags: xpath

I have HTML like this, and I want to get only those `<p>` tags that have the next sibling `<ul>` only.

```
<div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <ul>...</ul>
    <p>3</p>
    <ul>...</ul>
</div>
```

In the above example, I only want XPath to return the second and third `<p>` tag. Not the first one. I have tried using following-sibling but that didn't work out.

Comment: Show how you *have tried using following-sibling*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath will get `p` with an `ul` immediate sibling
`//p[./following-sibling::*[position()=1][name()="ul"]]`

or

```
//p[./following-sibling::*[position()=1 and name()="ul"]]
```

Testing on command line

```
xmllint --html --recover --xpath '//p[./following-sibling::*[position()=1][name()="ul"]]' test.html
```

Result

```
<p>2</p><p>3</p>
```

> The name function returns a string representing the QName of the first node in a given node-set.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name

According to the above, `position()=1 and name()="ul"` is probably redundant and `name()="ul"` would be enough.